# How to Add a Textbox over an Animated Image?

Tags: css, web, textbox

I am making a webpage with an image at center and i wanted a password field(textbox on the image) like this.[image]

I used Some CSS3 animations in the image so is there's any way that i could place my text box on the image without affecting any css animation??

Comment: some sample code would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the above case use :
position:absolute

what it does is simply disassociates the elements from is siblings and can be placed anywhere holding a reference to its parents.
Means if you want to position the element , use left/right of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

As he said in the comment sample code would be nice, however you could try using absolute position in your css for the image this will allow overlapping, I cannot give any specific code but it will be similar to what is below.

```
{
position:absolute;
}
```